# How to read .doc file line by line in java using all necessary jar file?

Tags: java, apache, file, xmlbeans

I want to display the difference between two .doc files line by line. I have done it with .txt files and it is working perfect. For this purpose I used the following code:

```
        FileReader File1Reader = new FileReader(File1.getPath());
        FileReader File2Reader = new FileReader(File2.getPath());

        // Create Buffered Object.
        BufferedReader File1BufRdr = new BufferedReader(File1Reader);
        BufferedReader File2BufRdr = new BufferedReader(File2Reader);

        // Get the file contents into String Variables.
        String File1Content = File1BufRdr.readLine();
        String File2Content = File2BufRdr.readLine();

        //New String Builder
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
```

Is there any way to read the doc files line by line.
I'm using following following code to read from doc file but this is not line by line. Here is the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.XWPFWordExtractor;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;

public class read_From_Doc_Docx {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            //Alternate between the two to check what works.
        //String FilePath = "D:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\Doc1.docx";
        String FilePath = "/Users/esna786/Removal of Redundancy.docx";
        FileInputStream fis;

        if (FilePath.substring(FilePath.length() - 1).equals("x")) { //is a docx
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(new File(FilePath).getAbsolutePath());
                XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(fis);
                XWPFWordExtractor extract = new XWPFWordExtractor(doc);
                System.out.println(extract.getText());
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else { //is not a docx
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(new File(FilePath));
                HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fis);
                WordExtractor extractor = new WordExtractor(doc);
                System.out.println(extractor.getText());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use getParagraphText() method instead of getText().